# When to use decodable, Codable, and encodable to retrieve data or send

Tags: swift, xcode

I am not entirely sure that ive been using the correct refrence points when I am fetching data from an API. I have used both Codable and decodable but I really dont understand the difference between the two, nor what the reference point of encodable means. Below I have created a web service request that will fetch the Json data from an API end point, and I am currently using the  a Decodable T.Type to retrieve that data, but I am not sure if I should be using Codable instead.

```
      import Foundation
      import UIKit

      //return error if API error
     enum ServiceError: Error {
     case decofailure
     case decocorrupt }


    class WebServiceRequest  {

     func loadData<T: Decodable>(url: URL, parse: (Data) -> T?) async 
     throws -> T {

    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
     
    
     if (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode != 200{
        throw ServiceError.decofailure
    }
 
    guard let result = parse(data) else {
        throw ServiceError.decocorrupt
    }
    return result
   }  



    }
```

Comment: see this docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

Comment: `Codable` means that the entity is both `Encodable` (ie can be encoded into data) and `Decodable` (can be decoded from data). When getting data from an API, you need `Decodable` data. `Codable` works as well, because it encompasses `Decodable`.

Comment: `Codable` is `Encodable` + `Decodable`. For JSON, which is the most common "codable" feature: `struct -> JSON`, that's `Encodable`, and `JSON -> struct`, that's `Decocable`, according to your needs use the correct one... So does your struct needs to be converted into JSON, or be decoded from JSON? Note that adding both (`Codable`, instead of only `Decocable` or only `Encodable` shouldn't that much an issue).

Comment: Unrelated, but Xcode will format your code for you if you select and use `CTRL-i`

Comment: Thank you all, I am getting data from a json end point, but I wanted to  really understand the differences as well as make sure that I was using the correct reference